# Invalid data provided22 in ./__swift/library/TemplateEngine/class.SWIFT_TemplateEngine.php:1091

Tags: php

Trying to upgrade Kayako to 4.50.
Downloaded and installed engage_stable_sourceobf_4_50_1636.tar.gz. 
Configured by following HOWTO: http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DOCS/Upgrading+your+helpdesk

However when I go to the new site I get the below error.

```
Uncaught Exception
Invalid data provided22 in ./__swift/library/TemplateEngine/class.SWIFT_TemplateEngine.php:1091
=================================================================================================================================

#0 ./__swift/library/TemplateEngine/class.SWIFT_TemplateEngine.php(113): SWIFT_TemplateEngine->LoadTemplateGroup(false)
#1 ./__swift/library/TemplateEngine/class.SWIFT_TemplateEngine.php(803): SWIFT_TemplateEngine->__construct(1)
#2 ./__swift/library/class.SWIFT.php(16): SWIFT_TemplateEngine::LoadEngine()
#3 ./__swift/library/class.SWIFT.php(16): SWIFT->Initialize()
#4 ./__swift/swift.php(16): SWIFT::GetInstance()
#5 ./index.php(28): require_once('/home/redpocket...')
#6 {main}
```

Has anyone came across this before?

Answer (score 1):

Found Answer:

When your Upgrading you need to go thru the Setup link http:///setup/, not the Main link http:///.